# Is there a solution for parsing json in SQL Server 2014

Tags: json, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to change the json format stored data in sql Server 2014 to a table like following:

```
Id  ImageId     FileNamePath
3    1          9/1/image1.png
3    1          9/1/image2.png
```

I have the following JSON (TestImage) stored in sql server 2014

```
Id  ImagingId   TestImage
3   1           [{"Filename":"9/1/image1.png","OriginalName":"image1.png"}, 
                {"Filename":"9/1/image2.png","OriginalName":"image2.png"}]
```

I searched the google and also stackoverflow that come with this website https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/
Created the parseJSON function

```
DECLARE @jsonInfo NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @jsonInfo=TestImage from rptImagings
Select Id, ImageId,
   max(case when name='Text' then convert(Varchar(50),StringValue) else '' 
end) as [Text],
   max(case when name='Value' then convert(Varchar(50),StringValue) else 
'' end) as [Value],
   max(case when name='Default' then convert(bit,StringValue) else 0 end) 
as [Default]
From parseJSON
(
@jsonInfo
)
where ValueType = 'string' OR ValueType = 'boolean'
group by parent_ID
```

I want the output result like following

```
Id  ImageId     FileNamePath
3    1          9/1/image1.png
3    1          9/1/image2.png
```

Comment: What does your JSON look like?

Comment: Id ImagingId TestImage
3 1 [{"Filename":"9/1/image1.png","OriginalName":"image1.png"},{"Filename":"9/1/image2.png","OriginalName":"image2.png"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option that will convert your JSON into XML.  From there it is a small matter of extraction

To be clear, this works with your sample data, but I suspect there may be issues down the road.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Id] varchar(50),[ImagingId] varchar(50),[TestImage] varchar(1500))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (3,1,'[{"Filename":"AA/9293/9/1/image1.png","OriginalName":"image1.png"},{"Filename":"AA/9293/9/1/image1.png","OriginalName":"image2.png"}]')

 Select A.ID
       ,A.ImagingId 
       ,C.*
From  YourTable A
Cross Apply ( values(try_convert(xml,replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace([TestImage],'[',''),']',''), '":"', '="'),'{"', '<x '),'}','></x>' ), '","','" ')) )) B(XMLData)
Cross Apply (
                Select FileNamePath = xAttr.value('.','varchar(max)')
                 From  XMLData.nodes('//@Filename') xNode(xAttr)
            ) C
```

**Returns**

```
ID  ImagingId   FileNamePath
3   1           AA/9293/9/1/image1.png
3   1           AA/9293/9/1/image1.png
```

Update [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=6365ada12420a95ee20a3aa736d21458)

Comment: Thank you it works fine with the data is "Filename":"9/1/image1.png" but when data is like "Filename":"AA/9293/9/1/image1.png" it does not work

Comment: @HafizullahMahmudi I can't replicate your issue see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=784fb5ec9ef3bb9ba64cd0fbd51023b7

Comment: @HafizullahMahmudi There has to be something else mucking up the works.

Comment: This is an issue but I don't know why. Here I am resharing the json [{"Filename":"AA/9293/9/1/image1.png","OriginalName":"image1.png"},{"Filename":"AA/9293/9/1/image2.png","OriginalName":"image2.png"}].  Please see there are two FileNames starting with "AA/.."

Comment: Please check. I can see problem but don't know solution. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=42514f2c4477d24830183b5febdbe360

Comment: @HafizullahMahmudi See updated answer.  Just removed the parsename() and added two replace() to remove the brackets.

Comment: @HafizullahMahmudi The conversion to xml was failing because of a shortcut using parsename()  this was removed and replaced with the proper replace functions.

Comment: @HafizullahMahmudi Updated my answer.   There is also a dbFiddle added to the bottom

Comment: @HafizullahMahmudi Perhaps refresh your browser  :)